# How to search a value for a particular key in NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionaries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Hello I have a `NSMutableDictionary` like this

```
<__NSArrayM 0x14e226ff0>(
{

DocumentName = "IMG_2597.JPG";
DocumentType = JPG;
Image = "<UIImage: 0x14e52c370> size {1239, 1242} orientation 0 scale 1.000000";

}
```

I am adding several objects into my `NSMutablearray`. But I want to check whether this image already available in the `NSMutablearray`. Actually I am planing to search it by the `DocumentName`. How can I check whether  that same value is already exists for the `DocumentName` key in the array. I want to add the `NSMutableDictionary` if only its not already exists. This is how I create my `NSMutabledictionary`object.

```
NSMutableDictionary *imageDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[imageDictionary setObject:chosenImage forKey:@"Image"];
[imageDictionary setValue:strDocNAme forKey:@"DocumentName"];
[imageDictionary setValue:strExtension forKey:@"DocumentType"];
[mutarrayImages addObject:imageDictionary];
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of these to check image is already exist or not.

**1) Using predicate**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"DocumentName = 'IMG_2597.JPG'"];
NSArray *arr = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if (arr.count > 0) {
    NSLog(@"Object is contain");
}
```

**2) Using valueForKey**

```
NSArray *documentName = [yourArray valueForKey:@"DocumentName"];
if ([documentName containsObject:@"IMG_2597.JPG"]) {
     NSLog(@"Object is contain");
}
```

Comment: my array can have several NSDictionaries. It's an array of dictionaries. So can I directly access like [arr containsObkect:@"IMG_2597.JPG"] no need to provide the index path?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSSet* myValuesSet = [NSSet setWithArray: [mutarrayImages valueForKey:@"DocumentName"]];
if ([[myValuesSet allObjects] containsObject:< DocumentName to compare >]) {
    NSLog(@"Exist");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Does not exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSArray *allObjectsArray;  // your array

NSMutableArray *resultObjectsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSDictionary *dict in allObjectsArray)
{
    NSString *docName = [dict objectForKey:@"DocumentName"];
    NSRange range = [docName rangeOfString:@"your string which you want to match" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if(range.location != NSNotFound)
        [resultObjectsArray addObject:dict];
}
```